# Use JavaScript to get JSF's Ajax active requests amount

Tags: javascript, ajax, selenium, jsf, jsf-2

I'm using JS in some Selenium tests to make sure there are no any active Ajax requests. I can extract their amount for jQuery and PrimeFaces but it doesn't work for JSF.

```
String jsPF = "return PrimeFaces.ajax.Queue.isEmpty();";
String jsJQuery = "return jQuery.active != 0;";
```

Is it possible to use JSF methods or pure JS to get it? Probably I have to use `"jsf.ajax.addOnEvent()"` but not sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the JSF API provides something like we do in PrimeFaces.

What do you would like to archive?

In PrimeFaces-Arquillian ([1](https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-arquillian)) we just use Graphene guards ([2](https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-arquillian/blob/master/primefaces-arquillian/src/main/java/org/primefaces/extensions/arquillian/component/CommandButton.java#L32)). This works perfectly fine if you would like to wait for an AJAX request:

```
Graphene.guardAjax(buttonToClick).click();
```

Comment: Graphene works for every element. It should work fine.
If you use PrimeFaces-Arquillian, you should even be able to use our CommandButton element with a JSF CommandButton.

Comment: Thanks, I have to make some additional research about it. Unfortunately, Graphene fails to run on my project.

Comment: Unfortunately, Graphene is not able to run on my project, so I can't use it now :(